# passbook pass not enter newline using "\r\n"

Tags: ios, passbook

I am using passbook, and have some input value, like this:

```
{
    "key" : "terms",
    "label" : "terms_contions",
    "value" : "1.aaaaaaa
               2.bbbbbbb 
               3.ccccccc
               4.ddddddd
}
```

I use "enter" key, I want to newline to see the value, but the pass show mistake.

so I modify it to:

```
{
    "key" : "terms",
    "label" : "terms_contions",
    "value" : "1.aaaaaaa 2.bbbbbbb 3.ccccccc 4.ddddddd
}
```

and all is ok, but I do not want  `1. 2. 3. 4.` at one line. I want to have 4 lines. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newlines will only work on back fields. Encode the newlines into the JSON like below and you should be OK.

```
{
    "key" : "terms",
    "label" : "terms_contions",
    "value" : "1.aaaaaaa\r\n2.bbbbbbb\r\n3.ccccccc\r\n4.ddddddd"
}
```

Example working pass with [newlines](https://r.pass.is/DC66BgbTQAUP/d) in the last backfield.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this is absolutely not working with me. So far I have tried \n and \r\n and <br/> both will not jump a new line

Comment: Can I confirm you are using for a back field?  Content on the front of the pass cannot span multiple rows.

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to add new lines in the backfields

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    "key" : "terms",
    "label" : "terms_contions",
    "value" : "1.aaaaaaa\n 2.bbbbbbb\n 3.ccccccc\n 4.ddddddd
}
```